# How do i add custom field on reopen issue page on jira's reopen issue page or screen

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I am trying to have a e-signature feature on jira's reopen issue page. It should have 2 custom field, which takes in username and password from the user.

Comment: Please give us the code where you have tried something out yourself

Comment: I figured out a way to added custom field to any workflow screen, using custom custom screens.